# DependencyProperty does not trigger LayoutProcess

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, dependency-properties

I am writing my own Panel (WPF) to draw a model. I have a Model-DependencyProperty and I want that any changes to my Model will affect a LayoutProcess.

```
ModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(Model), typeof(ModelPanel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
```

How should I implement my Model-Class so that any changes will affect a LayoutProcess? I've tried INotifyPropertyChanged. But it didn't work.

Comment: There should be nothing else necessary. Setting `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure` should result in a new layout cycle whenever the property has changed.

Comment: @Clemens but since he is using a Model, I'll bet its not the ModelProperty that changes, but the ModelProperty.Properties that change.

Comment: Yes I know. Using int, double and string as DP-Type does work. But Model is an object and I don't know how DependencyProperty works and recognizes that this object has changed. My panel does not register to my PropertyChangedHandler (using INotifyPropertyChanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this, but I think you might be going about this the wrong way.

In WPF the panel is simply supposed to define how things get laid out.

- A [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) places things one after another, horizontally or vertically.
- A [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) lays things out in a row/column then wraps to the next.
- A [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) lets you position things at x,y points.

Since you are attempting to use a panel, I assume you have a collection of things in your model. We can handle the collection with a `ListBox` which we can give the correct panel type to. i.e.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

However this commonly just gives us a list of class names, each one representing one of your Things, you need to tell WPF how to display it, and for this you use a `DataTemplate`. You can define these in many places, in a resources section (for the control, window or application) or just where you need it.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> <!-- Assuming each thing has a name property-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Update:
Or if you have different types of items to show

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <Canvas/>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyLine}">
            <Line x1="{Binding Left}" x2="{Binding Right}" 
                  y1="{Binding Top}" y2="{Binding Bottom}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyRectangle}">
            <Border Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Right="{Binding Right}" 
                    Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Canvas.Bottom="{Binding Bottom}"/>
        </DataTemplate>        
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Also have a read through [Josh Smith's article on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), it has a lot of examples and good practice in there, and will introduce a pattern that keeps your models cleaner.

Comment: The Problem is, my model does not have a list. It has many objects. These objects should be drawn to screen (rectangle, lines, text, etc). Changing an object in my model affects other objects in this model. So a change in one object means, more than this object have to be redrawn in my view. And I cannot use WPF. My model changes dynamically

Comment: By list I mean IEnumerable<T>, the same as you mean by Many. So its still the same paradigm, however it does sound as if a canvas might be what you are looking for. See latest update

Comment: I am trying Canvas and it seems to be the better way. Some of my objects should be grouped, so I place them in Grid and I place these grids in a Canvas. Seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: Better not `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Bottom`. The first takes precedence and then `Bottom` will be ignored.